# Specified generic type to implement Clone but type doesn't have Clone method

Tags: rust

I have code like this, where I need to insert something into two separate hashmaps. I only want generic types that implement Clone.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::clone::Clone;

pub struct Something<A, B> {
    hm1: HashMap<usize, B>,
    hm2: HashMap<usize, B>,
    other: A,
}

impl<A, B> Something<A, B>
    where B: Clone
{
    fn add_to_both_hm(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize, weight: B) {
        self.hm1.insert(x, weight.Clone());
        self.hm2.insert(y, weight);
    }
}
```

But when compiling, the compiler complains that `error: no method named 'Clone' found for type 'B' in the current scope`.

Why does it still error even though I specified `where B: Clone`? How can I fix that?

[The rust playground is here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=92e938f95d44c456abcc8c4d24e6168c&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: The method is `clone`.  Rust is a case-sensitive language.  **Edit**: I just realised what your problem might be: `Clone` is not a method, it's a trait, and the name of a trait doesn't have to have anything to do with the name of the methods it defines.

Comment: @DK. you're right, the misspelling of 'clone' is the issue here. Could you write this as an answer so it can be accepted/upvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible answers:

1. The method is called `clone` with a lower-case `c`.  Rust is a case-sensitive language.
2. `Clone` is not a method, it's a trait.  The name of a trait doesn't have anything to do with the name(s) of any methods it might define.  In `Clone`'s case, it defines a method `clone` for implementing types.

The solution in both cases is simple: write `weight.clone()` instead.